# Getting error on calling subquery in spark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am newbie in spark. i am doing a project where i am converting the sql server query through spark SQL using pyspark.
Here i am running a query

```
spark.sql("SELECT b.entityid                        AS EntityID, 
       cm.bldgid                                    AS BldgID, 
       cm.leasid                                    AS LeaseID, 
       COALESCE(l.suitid, (SELECT emptydefault 
                           FROM   emptydefault))    AS SuiteID, 
       cm.inccat                                    AS IncomeCat, 
       (SELECT currdateint 
        FROM   currdateint)                         AS AsAtDate, 
       COALESCE(CASE 
                  WHEN cm.department = '@' THEN (SELECT emptydept 
                                                 FROM   emptydept) 
                  ELSE cm.department 
                END, (SELECT emptydept 
                      FROM   emptydept))            AS Dept, 
       cm.tranamt 
       + COALESCE((SELECT Sum(amt) FROM cmledgapply cma JOIN cmledg cm2 ON 
       cma.tranid = 
       cm2.tranid AND cm2.trandate <= (SELECT currdate2 FROM currdate2) AND 
       (cm2.glref 
       IS NULL OR cm2.glref = 'N') WHERE cma.ptranid = cm.tranid), 0) - 
       COALESCE((SELECT Sum(amt) 
                 FROM   cmledgapply cma 
                        JOIN cmledg cm2 
                          ON cma.ptranid = cm2.tranid 
                             AND cm2.trandate <= (SELECT currdate2 
                                                  FROM   currdate2) 
                             AND ( cm2.glref IS NULL 
                                    OR cm2.glref = 'N' ) 
                 WHERE  cma.tranid = cm.tranid), 0) AS OpenAmt, 
       cm.trandate                                  AS InvoiceDate, 
       Datediff(cm.trandate, (SELECT currdate 
                              FROM   currdate)), 
       CASE 
         WHEN period.dateclsd IS NULL THEN 'Open' 
         ELSE 'Closed' 
       END                                          AS GLClosedStatus, 
       'Unposted'                                   AS GLPostedStatus, 
       'Unpaid'                                     AS PaidStatus 
FROM   cmledg cm 
       JOIN bldg b 
         ON cm.bldgid = b.bldgid 
       JOIN leas l 
         ON cm.bldgid = l.bldgid 
            AND cm.leasid = l.leasid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN period 
                    ON b.entityid = period.entityid 
                       AND cm.period = period.period 
WHERE  cm.trandate <= (SELECT currdate2 
                       FROM   currdate2) 
       AND Round(( cm.tranamt 
                   + COALESCE((SELECT Sum(amt) FROM cmledgapply cma JOIN cmledg 
                   cm2 ON 
                       cma.tranid 
                             = 
                   cm2.tranid AND cm2.trandate <= (SELECT currdate2 FROM 
                   currdate2) AND 
                             (cm2.glref 
                   IS NULL OR cm2.glref = 'N') WHERE cma.ptranid = cm.tranid), 0 
                   ) - 
                               COALESCE((SELECT Sum(amt) 
                                         FROM   cmledgapply cma 
                                                JOIN cmledg cm2 
                                                  ON cma.ptranid = cm2.tranid 
                                                     AND cm2.trandate <= (SELECT 
                                                         currdate2 
                                                                          FROM 
                                                         currdate2) 
                                                     AND ( cm2.glref IS NULL 
                                                            OR cm2.glref = 'N' ) 
                                         WHERE  cma.tranid = cm.tranid), 0) ), 2 
           ) <> 0 
       AND ( cm.glref IS NULL 
              OR cm.glref = 'N' )").show()
```

basically inside spark.sql() it is one line code.i have just formatted it for reading easily. 
i am getting error like this

> u"Invalid call to dataType on unresolved object, tree:
>   'coalesce(scalar-subquery#1402 [], 0)

i have tried some debugging it seems the error has occurred in  last two coalesce or near about it. but i am not figured it yet. It will be very help full  if anyone give me some guidelines.point to note that  CurrDate is date type table and  CurrDate2 is  timestamp  type. I am using pyspark here

Thank you  in advance

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: i have figured out the possible bug. the coalesce  function in openAmt . here i am comparing trandate with currdate . if i give a hard coded timestamp value it works but  i am fetching a currdate from a table in spark . some how  the comparison is not referring the  currdate value from currdate table . how could i do that  any suggestion